# Creating a moving bar (inside the nav bar) which moves to the element the user hovers on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I'm trying to create a `nav bar` which consists of the regular navigation elements and an indication bar which is located below the current page. My goal is to make this bar move under whichever element the user hovers on and automatically resize itself according to a pre-defined size (according to the word length maybe?). I built the `nav bar` itself, but I'm kind of clueless how to achieve this effect. Should I always calculate the current position of the mouse and add the difference between the current location and the hover location? Regarding to the resizability, this is a secondary goal, less significant.

This is what I've done so far:
Html:

```
<header class="header">
            <div class="logo"> 
                <nav id="nav_bar">
                    <ul id="nav_ul">
                        <li><a href="#">apples</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">bananas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">tomatos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">onions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="container">
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

CSS:

```
#nav_ul a{
    color: #685e6d;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
   transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_ul{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav_ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 90px;
    bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#nav_ul a:hover{
    color: #4ad1fd;
}


#container{
    position: relative;
    left: 167px;
    height: auto;
    width: 530px;
    top: 5px;
}

#bar{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 7px;
    width: 107px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sp30vkum/)

Something like in this image:
[image]

Comment: Do you need this to be a CSS-only solution or are you open to scripting this?

Comment: Open to any suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create a **lavalamp** menu, checkout the example below...

```css
/* ---- reset ------*/
html, body, div, a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

html {
  line-height: 1; }


/* --- basic styles ----*/

body {
  font-family: "Unica One";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white; }

/* --- for this example ----*/

.nav {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 480px;
  position: relative; }
  .nav a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em 0 2em;
    width: 25%;
  text-decoration: none;
   color: #393939;
   -webkit-transition: .7s;
   -moz-transition: .7s;
   -o-transition: .7s;
   -ms-transition: .7s;
   transition: .7s; }
   .nav a:hover {
     color: #c6342e; }

.effect {
 position: absolute;
  left: -12.5%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.7s ease-in-out; }

 .nav a:nth-child(1):hover ~ .effect {
   left: 12.5%; }
 .nav a:nth-child(2):hover ~ .effect {
   left: 37.5%; }
 .nav a:nth-child(3):hover ~ .effect {
   left: 62.5%; }
 .nav a:nth-child(4):hover ~ .effect {
   left: 87.5%; }

/* ----- line example -----*/

.ph-line-nav .effect {
  width: 90px;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 36px;
  background: #c6342e;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white; 
  margin-left:-45px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="ph-line-nav nav">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Gallery</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <div class="effect"></div>
 </div>
```

Find more here http://pepsized.com/css-only-lavalamp-like-fancy-menu-effect/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery solution: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sp30vkum/4/) for if the code snippet doesn't work)

```js
function BarMove(el) {
    var bar = $('#bar');
    var width = el.outerWidth();
    var left = el.offset().left;
    bar.animate({
        width: width,
        left: left
    });
}
var Current = $('#nav_ul li a.current'); // Set the current page
BarMove(Current);
$('#nav_ul li a').hover(function () {
    BarMove($(this));
}, function () {
    BarMove(Current);
});
```

```css
#nav_ul a {
    color: #685e6d;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav_ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 90px;
    bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#nav_ul a:hover {
    color: #4ad1fd;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 530px;
    top: 5px;
}

#bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 7px;
    width: 107px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <nav id="nav_bar">
            <ul id="nav_ul">
                <li><a href="#" class="current">apples</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">bananas</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">tomatos</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">onions</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

It's not exact, so you'll need to tweak the numbers but functionality is what you're after as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you have `#nav_ul a:hover` so you could add `border-bottom-style: solid; border-color:<color>` and you would have a bar appear under your items. It wouldn't slide, or be animated. It will, however, put a colored bar under what ever they are hovering over.